# How to update price total before changing the quanity

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a woocomemrce website and currently relying on a plugin called Product Price x Quantity preview. The problem is, you dont see the preview of the total price until the value is changed on the quantity. The quantity starts at 10 so Ideally I want the price to work out quantity x individual price.

You can see the page here: http://peamoreflora.kneedeepdesign.co.uk/product/aconitum-monkshood/ 
When you change the quantity, the total price will display.

I have tried forcing/simulating the quantity change via jQuery on page load:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'bbloomer_custom_action', 5 );

function bbloomer_custom_action() { ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $(".quantity .qty").change();
    });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

That doesnt seem to do anything. Any tips, help or advice will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should search for a function which triggers on quantity changes but still if you are not able to do so, you can follow below code which is a temporary fix for this issue.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        let existingValue = $(".quantity .qty").val();
        $(".quantity .qty").val(0);
        $(".quantity .qty").val(existingValue);
});
</script>
```

Basically I am changing its input value twice. Hope it helps you but still it is not reliable one.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the code block. It looks as though the page is loading with the value of 1, then some script (probably from the plugin) is later changing the quantity value to 10. Therefore my snippet is overridden.